# How to integrate two collections into one?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple collections (like 2 collections but it might be more) in one array like this :

```
var attributes = [ { colors: [ 10, 20, 30 ] }, { dimensions: [ a, b] } ]
```

And I want to have somthing like this :

```
var newArray =  [ {10 : a },{ 10 : b },{20 : a},{20 : b},{30 : a},{30 : b} ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to *"integrate"* the two collections into one? Please show your attempt(s) as this will give myself and others something to work with and enable some detail of why your attempt didn't give the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Also wouldn't you rather have the output structured like this `[{ a:[10,20,30], b:[10,20,30]}]`? Then you could target `newArray[0]` to return the properties `a`,`b` and you can target the array of values by using `newArray[0].a`. This suggestion might be useful to you but then again it might be the exact opposite of what you need. Hard to tell without understand the reason for your expected output and hard to give a helpful answer to explain why your current attempt isn't working without seeing what you are currently trying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand what you'd like to have in case of more than two items in the outer array, but here's a solution for your example:

```js
var attributes = [{
  colors: [10, 20, 30]
}, {
  dimensions: ["a", "b"]
}];
var newArray = [];
attributes[0].colors.forEach(color => {
  attributes[1].dimensions.forEach(dim => {
    var obj = {};
    obj[`${color}`] = dim;
    newArray.push(obj);
  });
});
console.log(newArray);
```

> Additional changes by NewToJS - `dimensions: [a, b]` **To** `dimensions: ["a", "b"]`

If you specify what you want more precisely, I'll try to edit the answer because it all depends on the details.

Comment: First thing than needs fixing is the  second array of  `attributes` because the array for the object property `dimensions` will cause a syntax error or at least it is for me using Hoogle Chrome **Update** Since it is only a minor error I will fix it for you and create your solution source code into a working snippet.

Comment: That's probably because `a` and `b` are undefined but that's how the question was asked, so I preserved the array. It worked fine in node with quoted elements.

Comment: If you see something that will cause a syntax error it should be corrected since this could be the reason the OP's current attempt isn't functioning as intended. Hard to know for sure since the OP hasn't shown/shared any attempt(s) of their own but without those changes to the array this would no work in a snippet making it a useless solution since should be fine to run as a snippet. Just trying to help improve your answer. You can undo the changes if you want.

Comment: No, not at all. I see your point and it makes sense. Thank you for the edit! :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I couldn't see much point in me posting a solution since it would be pretty close to what you currently have  other than a few additional options. Good work :) I will +1 for giving a working solution giving the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely depends. But, if the `attribute` data will always be structured as you describe it, this will do the trick.

```
    var attributes = [ { colors: [ 10, 20, 30 ] }, { dimensions: [ "a","b"] } ]

    function crossReference(attributes, key, scope){
        let result = [];
        let variables = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
        if(!key && key !== 0){ 
            attributes.forEach((attr, key)=>{
                let keys = Object.keys(attr);
                keys.forEach((property)=>{
                    if(Array.isArray(attr[property])){
                        console.log(property);
                        result= result.concat(crossReference(attr[property], key, attributes));
                        // section.forEach()
                    }
                })

            })
        }else{
            console.log(attributes, scope[key+1], key);
            attributes.forEach((attr,index)=>{
                if(!scope[key+1]) return;
                let next = scope[key+1];
                let keys = Object.keys(scope[key+1]);
                keys.forEach((property)=>{
                    if(Array.isArray(next[property])){
                        next[property].forEach((prop)=>{
                            result.push({[attr]:prop})
                        })


                    }
                })

            })
        }
        return result;
    }

    console.log(crossReference(attributes))
```

Comment: What in gods name..... you do not need all of this for the expected output in the OP's question. You have over complicated/worked a simple task. **Also** what do you mean by *"if the attribute data will always be structured"*?